# jQuery method attached to $()

Tags: jquery

I have to display the content of two data sets. One is xml, the other I have put in an array of structures/objects. I want to process them in the same manner. I did:

```
{
    if( FileType == FILE_TYPE_XML )
    {
        $( XmlLogData ).find( "LogRecord" ).each( function()
        {
            $.fn.ProcessLogTree_( $( this ) );
        });
    }
    if( FileType == FILE_TYPE_JSN )
    {
        $( SerialLogData ).each( function()
        {

            LogElemTemp = this; // naive way
            LogElemTempWrap = $( LogElemTemp ); // naive way
            LogElemTempWrap.text = function() { return LogElemTemp.text(); }; // naive way
            LogElemTempWrap.parent = function() { return $( LogElemTemp.Parent() ); }; // naive way

            $.fn.ProcessLogTree_( $(this) );
            //$.fn.ProcessLogTree_( LogElemTempWrap ); // naive way
        });
    }
}
$.fn.ProcessLogTree_ = function( LogElemWrap )
{
    if( FileType == FILE_TYPE_JSN ) LogElemWrapUp = ???;
    if( FileType == FILE_TYPE_XML ) LogElemWrapUp = LogElemWrap.parent();
    NewLine = LogElemWrap.text();
    ...
```

I took xml processing part from an example I found and works fine. The thing is that in case of xml, parents() and text() seem to be attached to  $(this) as seen in ProcessLogTree_() ?! How it is done?!
In case of member data I can write

```
var x = LogElemWrap.attr( "Desc" );
```

for both data sets (xml and the other one) but does not really work for member methods. I don't even know, how to call a method wrapped in $()? I tried

```
(LogElemWrap.attr( "text" ))()()
```

but doesn't work and actually is not what I want because I want ProcessLogTree_ to have nothing data set type dependent. Anyway, I would like to know how to do it.

As I have shown, my naive way was to attach some wrapper before calling  ProcessLogTree_(). This works for a function like text() but in case of parent(), the problem is that almost works except that, of course, the parent doesn't also have a parent() method (so I can go up from parent to parent) because the parent() functions are not actually attached to original data set. So:

- how to call a member method of an object wrapped in $()?
- how to attach a method to $() and redirect execution to the corresponding method of the wrapped object?

Comment: using `jQuery.fn.someMethod = function...` will help you attach a method to `$()` and use it as `$().someMethod`

Comment: @Neville Nazerane In the JSN "if" section I added

    $( SerialLogData_NoRoot ).each( function()
    {
        let LogElem = this;
        jQuery.fn.text = function() { return LogElem.Text(); };
        LogTree = ProcessLogTree_( $(this), LogTreeContainer );
    });

Starnge enough, also XmlLogData is affected.